# search an array in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

this is what i am trying to do :

```
 $allwinnersarra = array(26809,26805,24279,4839,20939,17678,4999,17745,1);

 $results_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM table_users WHERE userid IN('".join("','", $allwinnersarra)."')"); 

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results_query)) {
        $usernamesFound.= $row['username'];
 }

 die($usernamesFound);
```

there is an array of id numbers and I want their usernames , in my own idea my approach is correct but the outcome is not.

The output is only the first username and does not show other usernames

Comment: if userid is numeric, don't put quotes around your values in the IN part or they get evaluated to string and you most probably get wrong result - not sure it this solves you problem though

Comment: @Basti I had problems with strings as integers when using IN before, so that's where I'm comming from... might be wrong, maybe it got "fixed" in the meanwhile

Comment: @Basti I am sure because these ids are from my user table , its just a test of command. but I am wonder why it only returns the first username.

Comment: Would you please export the table and some tuples, that should be returned? (Create a minimum working example.)

Comment: @mac-taylor - remove single quotes before the braces in your query. It should be `mysql_query("SELECT username FROM table_users WHERE userid IN(".join("','", $allwinnersarra).")");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$allwinnersarra = array(26809,26805,24279,4839,20939,17678,4999,17745,1);
$allwinnersarra = implode( ',', $allwinnersarra );

$sql = "SELECT username FROM table_users WHERE userid IN 
          (" . mysql_real_escape_string( $allwinnersarra ) . ");";
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: you did nothing but aliasing join which was a suggestion by my answer, good job buddy

Comment: @peipst9lker - `(" . mysql_real_escape_string( $allwinnersarra ) . ")`  notice the absence of single quotes just before the opening/closing braces as in your example (the reason why you are getting just one result)...anyway good luck.

Comment: Why I am getting  Notice: Array to string conversion error on the line implode

Answer (score 2):

1. Is $usernamesFound even a string? Please declare it above the loop.
2. Add a whitespace between the variable name and the .=-operator
3. I would suggest you putting the usernames in an array

   $users = array();

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results_query)) { $users[] = $row['username']; }
4. Also please use implode instead of join.

Comment: $usernamesFound  if you see I used  usernamesFound .=  so it surely is a string.

Comment: $usernamesFound not beeing defined will in the worst case trigger a notice. Whitespaces don't matter. String concatenation vs array doesn't matter. `Join` is an alias of `implode`, so they are the same. And again an upvote for a useless answer. =_="

Comment: @MacTaylor if you declare it as an array and then use .= it'll rain warnings and errors (while-loop)

Comment: @peipst9lker and for the record I have used the array approach you mentioned but it returns  
Array
(
    [0] => wiliam
)

Comment: @Basti Whitespace's doesnt matter but its improving the clearness. I suggest implode because most people use it and its senseless that everyone uses aliases for everything

Comment: @MacTaylor Are you sure that the ID's exist in your table?

Comment: @peipst9lker These are all only your personal preferences. They have nothing to do with the question and won't help solve it.